# UITableView Animating UImageView

Tags: iphone

How do I animate a UIImageView from UITableview with the flying effect?

Comment: what is a flying effect?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you mean by the 'flying effect', pretty much any animation is possible using CoreAnimation.

Grab the UIImageView instance's layer and animate it as you wish.

Info on CoreAnimation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).